# How do I use the '&' correctly when binding in a directive in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have having trouble with understanding the `&` option in binding scope properties. I have read these tutorials: [angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes](http://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/), [practical-guide-angularjs-directives](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/) and [the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/) as well as looking at the documentation but I am completely confused about how to use the `&` symbol.

Here is my attempt at using it:

```
var app = angular.module('directivesApp');
app.directive('simplyIsolated', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            attnum: '@numone'
            ,bindnum: '=numtwo'
            ,expressnum: '&sq'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr){
           scope.x = scope.expressnum();
        },
        template:'<div><p> using "@" = {{attnum+attnum}}</p>'+
                        '<p>using "=" {{bindnum+bindnum}}</p>'+
                        '<p>using "&" {{x}}</p><br/><p>{{y}}</p>'+
                '</div>'

    };

}) 
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.sqr = function(num){
        return num*num;
    }

});
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="num1parent" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="num2parent" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="num3parent" />
    <p>Parent Scope @ {{usernameparent}}, 
        = {{userageparent}}, 
        & = {{sqr(num3parent)}}
    </p>
    <div simply-isolated numone='{{num1parent}}' numtwo='num2parent' sq="sqr"></div>
</div>
```

This is the result.
[image]
the first two inputs are used to show the difference between `@` and `=`. The third input is used to show the `sqr()` method works but in the text underneath the `using "&"` is supposed to be the square of the 2nd input but I don't get any result or error

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it

Also: Why would you use the `&` over `scope.$parent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because you're not using the function scope.x as a function instead you have it evaluated as a mere function expression with no argument value.

try changing the template to this:

```
template:'<div><p> using "@" = {{attnum+attnum}}</p>'+
  '<p>using "=" {{bindnum+bindnum}}</p>'+
  '<p>using "&" {{x(bindnum}}</p><br/><p>{{y}}</p>'+
'</div>'
```

that should show something when you provide changes in the num2parent model.

> Why would you use the & over scope.$parent?

Because it is normally not recommended to do so, if you would be doing it in such a manner it might be better not to isolate the scope of your directive and have direct access to the parent controllers properties in the directive.

Update:

The reference passed by the attribute notiation '&' is a function that returns the function defined in your controllers. To invoke the function reference, simply do this:

```
{{expressnum()(bindNumb)}}
```

that will do the trick.
Note:
There is a reason for this, functions often passed via '&' attribute notations are function callbacks such as events. So if your `exressnum()` was an callback function for an event then it would have been used like this in you template perhaps

```
<a ng-click="expressnum()">Click Expression</a>
```

Furthermore, the function `sqr()` is a type of function that changes the result of an expression, such functions must be defined as a filter.

Comment: why can I not use `'<p>using "&" {{expressnum(bindnum}}</p>'` , I do I need to assign it to another scope property in order to use it

Comment: This is because the reference passed in the attribute notation '&' is  technically a function that returns the callback function specified in the value of the attribute. To invoke it as the function defined in your controllers then you must do it like this:
{{expressnum()(bindnum}}